# webpack encore / symfony 5 scripts loading order

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, twig, symfony5

I have a problem on the script loading order in symfony 5  / webpack encore.

The scripts doesn't load in the right order...

For the exemple i have made this simple test : two documents ready fonction with Jquery Version :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($().jquery);
});
```

one in my app.js call in my base.html.twig  (call first normally)
and another in my page.

When you run the page, the alert version in my page show first with a 'undefined version" and then the alert in app.js work correctly.

Normally app.js is call first so i don't understand why the second document ready is call first.

thanks for you help !

App.js

```
    /*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
import '../css/app.css';

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to import it.
import $ from 'jquery';
// uncomment if you have legacy code that needs global variables
// global.$ = $;

import 'bootstrap';


require('../css/global.scss');


$(document).ready(function() {

    alert($().jquery);
    console.log('Version')
});
```

Webpack config

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    // this is your *true* public path
    .setPublicPath('/athena/build')

    // this is now needed so that your manifest.json keys are still `build/foo.js`
    // (which is a file that's used by Symfony's `asset()` function)
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    //Datagrid
    .addEntry('jqwidgetsDataGrid', './assets/js/jqwidgetsDataGrid.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    // .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    //enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
   //.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning()

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })



    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // Intégration des fichiers et images statiques
    // .copyFiles({
    //     from: './assets/md',
    //     to: './md/[name].[ext]'
    // })
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    })
//
    // Transformation du css pour l'ensemble des navigateurs
    // .enablePostCssLoader((options) => {
    //     options.config = {
    //         path: 'config/postcss.config.js'
    //     };
    // })


    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Athena{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {# Zone menu #}
        {% include("partials/navbar.html.twig") %}

        {# Corps de la page #}
        <div class="mx-3">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>

        {# Javascript #}
        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

My page :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('jqwidgetsDataGrid') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Permissions de l'application{% endblock %}

{# Ajout des Popups et modals #}
{% use 'permissions/modalform.html.twig' with global as addPerm_global %}

{% block body %}



    <div class="spacer-orange rounded-top mt-3"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid parker-fond-page rounded-bottom ">

        <h1>Liste des Permissions</h1>
        {{ dump(permissions) }}
        {% for permission in permissions %}
            <H2>{{ permission.Name }}</H2>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>


    <div class="spacer-orange rounded-top mt-3"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid parker-fond-page rounded-bottom ">
        <div id="jqxgrid">
        </div>
    </div>

{#    Ajout modals #}
    {% set form_id = "formAjoutPerm" %}
    {% set modal_id = "modalAjoutPerm" %}
    {% set modal_title = "Ajout d'une permission" %}
    {% set form_action = path('permissions_ajaxadd') %}
    {% set namespace = "addForm" %}
    {{ block('addPerm_global') }}


{% endblock %}




{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('jqwidgetsDataGrid') }}

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {

            alert($().jquery);
           // show first but doesn't work ???? 

        }); //fin documentready function
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Is there a reason you want to use it this way? A big point of Webpack is to keep all your on-site scripts nicely contained in classes and entry points that are called when needed. In general the only js code you want directly in your templates is 3rd party code like analytics or tracking pixels for ad networks, that kind of thing.